# How to install OpenStack Mitaka + OVS Bridge + DVR

Tags: openstack

All:

I want to install OpenStack Mitaka + OVS Bridge + DVR for CentOS-7 and i don't want to use any automatic tools but RDO. However i can't find any installation guides for my purpose, which confuse me very much!

Can anyone give me some help here? Thanks advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I know you don't want to use automated tools, but, I have automated installers constructed in basic shell language (sh), which includes both Centos 7 using RDO repos, and Ubuntuses using ubuntu-cloud-archive.

The reason I'm using simple shell instead of puppet or ansible, is due the fact I also use them for teach people how to "manually install" OpenStack. You can see my installers on my site at github, and specifically the one you need for Mitaka (I'll publish the Newton-based in about two weeks):

https://github.com/tigerlinux/openstack-mitaka-installer-centos7

Note that due the fact my installer is completely modular, and each module takes care of a single component, it can be easier to you to self-teach yourself how to manually install OpenStack.

Also, I have some I.T. recipes in the following link, with a section with tips-and-tricks for OpenStack:

http://tigerlinux.github.io/

It's not much, but I hope it helps you !.